# Ruby Postgresql Sort database table info by specific column's data in a loop

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I don't even know how to ask this correctly, so pardon me if my question is confusing.  I have a Table called Colors -

[image: Sample Colors Table]

I would like to iterate a list of all the colors in the table, but presorted by 'color-family' so the result would look something like this:

```
Colors:
   Reds -
      Maroon
      Stop Sign
   Yellows -
      Canary
   Blues - 
      Sky Blue
      Royal Blue
   Greens -
      Neon Green
```

But I have no idea the sql syntax to collect and sort that kind of information.
Surprisingly, this code didn't work ;)

```
<% @group = Colors.presort_by("color-family") %> 
<% @color = Colors.all %>
<% @group.each do |group| %>
  <%= group.color-family %>s - <br>
  <% if @color.name.has_a_column_that_is_also_the_@group.color-family %>
  <%= @color.name %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

lol.  As you can see, I have no real idea where to start.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I don't have any sql query experience whatsoever.

Thanks again!

Comment: `@colors = Color.order(:color-family ,:name)` something like this, depends what order you want. You could reference [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this using just ActiveRecord query methods. But it can easily be done in-memory using Ruby's [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), and the performance will be good unless it's a large data set (in which case you'd probably want to cache the results, or look into a more complex SQL query)

```
@colors = Color.all
grouped = @colors.group_by { |color| color.color_family }
# or             .group_by &:color_family
```

This will return a hash where keys are color family (strings) and values are arrays of Color records.